# Foundation Sass, Accordion and Tabs not working

Tags: javascript, tabs, sass, zurb-foundation, accordion

I am having problems with Foundation and the Accordion and Tabs modules. I created my project using the command line `compass create <project name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation` and I then customized the style sheet using Sass and the `_settings.scss`.
Although, I can't get the Accordion and Tabs modules working and I don't understand why. I realized that both `foundation.accordion.js` and `foundation.tab.js` files do not come with, in the JS folder when creating a project like I did. I therefore decided to put them myself there from a standard downloading of Foundation but it is still not working. I obviously included the script tags for them at the end my Html page.

Do you guys know if there's any possibility to create a Foundation project using Sass that includes those two modules? I can't use the standard Foundation since I am like customizing everything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem. I used to create foundation projects using the command above. Although, I realized it is preferable to create the project using `foundation new PROJECT_NAME` (NodeJS and Bower are needed). Like this, everything comes along, including the `foundation.accordion.js` and the `foundation.tab.js`.

Actually, it is the last version of Foundation that is downloaded and everything works perfectly like this.